# IFrame event executes fine in HTML but not in HTA

Tags: html, vbscript, hta

This HTML file shows message dialog when button inside iframe is clicked:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="VBScript" type="text/vbscript">

      Sub load_me()
        frame.document.write "<input type='button' onclick='parent.message()'>"
      End Sub

      Sub message()
        MsgBox "Hi"
      End Sub

    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <iframe id="frame" onload="load_me"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

While same document as HTA file, raises error: `Error: Object doesn't support this property or method`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <HTA:APPLICATION
      APPLICATIONNAME="Test"
      ID="MyHTMLapplication"
      VERSION="1.0"/>

    <script language="VBScript">

      Sub load_me()
        frame.document.write "<input type='button' onclick='parent.message()'>"
      End Sub

      Sub message()
        MsgBox "Hi"
      End Sub

    </script>
  </head>

  <body bgcolor="white">
    <iframe id="frame" onload="load_me"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why is that, or how can I execute parent function with `onclick` event from iframe button in HTA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use:

```
<iframe id="frame" onload="load_me" application="yes"></iframe>
```

See [Intro to .HTA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), section **The Power of Trust: HTAs and Security**