# Open a Website in HTA application

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, web, hta

So, I have this small local website, which is the website that opens when you open router configuration. that is, 192.168.0.1. the one in which we make settings for the router. I need to open that website very frequently for turning the wireless on and off and I have to do it via a browser. Its bit of a heavy process, so I decided to switch to one click HTA applications which makes the work very Quick.
The thing is, whenever the home screen of that website opens, where you have to put the router password, after inputting the proper password, the website in the HTA won't redirect to the Preferences page, like it does in the Browser. It stays at the Login page and I have no idea if I have to put some extra piece of code in my HTA. Please help.

Below is the code.

```
<html>
    <head> 
    </head> 
    <body> 
        <iframe src="http://192.168.0.1" width="100%" height="100%"> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IFrame event executes fine in HTML but not in HTA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14834888/iframe-event-executes-fine-in-html-but-not-in-hta)

Answer (score 1):

Because of the security risk that HTAs can pose accessing
URLs through `<iframe>` tags is locked down, but you can tell the engine that a `<iframe>` is trusted by adding the `application="yes"` attribute.

> <sup>Quote from [Introduction to HTML Applications (HTAs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496.aspx)</sup>
> <sub>Section: The Power of Trust: HTAs and Security</sub>
>
> ---
>
> ***HTAs are designed such that untrusted HTML frame and iframe objects have no script access to the HTA containing them**. In the case of frame objects that are not HTA-enabled, the highest level frame comprises the top window for all frame objects it contains. For that frame object, the window.top and window.self properties are one and the same. In addition, unsafe frame and iframe objects receive neither a referrer nor an opener URL from the parent HTA. The end result is that they are unaware of the containing HTA as the parent window.*

Using the example in the question;

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <HTA:APPLICATION
            APPLICATIONNAME="Test"
            ID="TestApp"
            VERSION="1.0"/>
    </head> 
    <body> 
      <iframe src="http://192.168.0.1" width="100%" height="100%" application="yes"> 
    </body> 
</html>
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [Introduction to HTML Applications (HTAs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536496.aspx)

Comment: thank you for efforts but that didn't work either. what happens with the above code is, when i open the HTA, at the same time it also opens IE and the '192.168.0.1' in it. and still the website in HTA won't work. If you would require, i could take the screen video of the entire thing and give you the link.

Comment: @krrish it which case you're implementing it wrong, I assure you this is the fix for loading content in an `<iframe>` in a MSHTA application trusted. Just so you know IE shouldn't open separately just follow the link in the answer to build a HTA properly. It also depends how the router page works, if it opens a pop up you don't have control of then neither using a HTA or a web page will get around it.

Comment: What if you set the default browser to an application you made yourself that can handle the calls to it and launches the MSHTA or your actual browser depending on the address. If it detects that the address is 192.168.0.1 it will open the HTA application you made, else it will launch your actual browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this Property in the HTA:APPLICATION tag :

NAVIGABLE="YES"

Also, keep application = "No"