# Iframe links not redirecting despite correct syntax (HTA file)

Tags: html, embed, hta

I am trying to embed a website in an HTML application that has links. I've tried this:

```
<iframe id="frame" application="yes"></iframe>
```

(I haven't really figured out the size) and it worked, just you can't use links on the page. I would usually just put the code of the webpage into the hta file, but there were some problems with javascript. I need to make a  multi-page site, so I need links. Is there a way to embed a website that has links onto an HTML app, and still keep the links working? Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can use an [`iframe` but will have some security considerations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14835146/692942) to deal with.

Comment: I just updated the question. It worked.